# About badly documented patreon-js

Tags: javascript, json, rest, patreon

I don't understand this documentation, I tried so hard to do the mentioned info below but I am not quite sure what "jsonApiURL" is. Can someone tell me how to properly achieve the goal in the quote.

> Response Format
>
> You can request specific related resources and or resource attributes
>   that you want returned by our API, as per the JSON:API specification.
>   The lists of valid includes and fields arguments are provided in
>   patreon/schemas. For instance, **if you wanted to request the total
>   amount a patron has ever paid to your campaign, which is not included
>   by default, you could do**:

```
const patreonAPIClient = patreonAPI(access_token)
const url = jsonApiURL(`/current_user`, {
  fields: {
    pledge: [...pledge_schema.default_attributes, pledge_schema.attributes.total_historical_amount_cents]
  }
})
patreonAPIClient(url, callback)
```

More info below

https://github.com/Patreon/patreon-js

Comment: https://github.com/Patreon/patreon-js/blob/master/src/jsonapi-url.js
In the patreon source this is probably what that line is referring to

Comment: @ScottFanetti I saw that but how do I make use of it?

Comment: import jsonApiURL from 'jsonapi-url'

Comment: They are using babel to transpile ES6 down to ES5 so that might be where you are getting a little hung up.  But you can also use the same sort of pattern with require.

Comment: @ScottFanetti Okay so I used require to require that as jsonApiURL now next error is 'pledge_schema is not defined'

Comment: @ScottFanetti And that is probably about https://github.com/Patreon/patreon-js/blob/master/src/schemas/pledge.js here but then how to? what? ... Their documentation is really so bad.